# CollectionVIew not rendering cell when collection count is 1

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboard

I am facing a challenge where my UICollectionView does not show an item when the collection count is 1. More specifically, it flashes briefly when calling reloadSections or does not show at all when calling reloadData.
This collectionview is present as an item inside a UITableViewCell.

Even though I am not using Xamarin, this post I found on a Xamarin board pretty much sums up what I am experiencing: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35471/cells-from-custom-uicollectionviewcontroller-disappear-after-a-second (after 1 second, my cell vanishes)

Everything is extremely basic:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
         return 1
     }
     
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.members.count  
     }
    
    
       //Rendering the collection view cells
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
               let member: GroupMemberDto = members[indexPath.item]
               let contactInitials = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
               let contactAvatar = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
               contactAvatar.image = UIImage(named: "anonymous")
               contactInitials.text = member.displayName
               contactAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = contactAvatar.frame.size.width / 2
               contactAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
               contactAvatar.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
               contactAvatar.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
               contactAvatar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
   

               UserService.getProfilePicture(userId: member.userId) {
                       response in
                       contactAvatar.image = response
               }
           

           return cell
       }
```

When I bind it to a collection of 10 items, it works. If, however, I go into "numberOfItemsInSection" and change this to return "1" instead of "self.members.count", it flashes the first member briefly then just disappears.

I'm convinced the issue is not related to code rather the UI - I came across a few other posts that tangentially mentioned things will not draw out or these odd bugs can occur, however I wasn't able to cobble together a definitive answer.

Could anyone guide me or offer some suggestions on what might be causing this?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is it that flashes and disappears?

Comment: The cell - I set the background to pink just to see, and the single cell appears as a pink box, then disappears after about 1/2 a second. I've also set the CollectionView background to orange, and that stays forever so I know the CollectionView itself isn't disappearing

Comment: So ask yourself: what happens 1/2 a second later? It's probably something you didn't show here, or it might be your line `contactAvatar.image = response`, that probably happens about 1/2 a second later eh. That is a bad way to update an image in a cell... Anyway, try commenting out that line and see if it solves the problem. If the problem still happens, the cause is code you didn't show us.

Comment: Something to think about though is why does it show temporarily for reloading the section (0) but if I just specify reloadData entirely, it never loads?

Comment: @matt i got it - it was indicator insets! Can't believe it. thanks for the help you got me down the right track by the of questioning (you made me think about what ui redrawing was occuring after 1/2 a second)

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I figured this out and hope it might help someone.

I went into the collectionview on the UIStoryBoard and set the content insets to 1 (previously they were 0) and in addition the scroll indicator insets to 1 as well (they were all 0).

After doing this, the item rendered and stayed rendered!